# Post a message to a specific MS Teams Channel using deep link

Tags: deep-linking, microsoft-teams

I am able to go to a specific channel using :

msteams://teams.microsoft.com/l/channel/channelid/General?groupId=groupid&tenantId=tenantid

but how do i send a message to the channel using deep linking URI?

I tried
msteams://teams.microsoft.com/l/channel/channelid/General?groupId=groupid&tenantId=tenantid&message=hello

but it just opens the channel in MSTeams

Comment: When you say "I tried..." , How did you try? Just a GET in the browser? A POST from curl/wget?

Comment: Hi, just a Get in the browser. I pasted the url to a browser and it redirects me to open ms teams. I am able to create a chat to a specific user using  something like 

msteams://teams.microsoft.com/l/chat/0/0?users=joe@contoso.com,bob@contoso.com&topicName=Prep%20For%20Meeting%20Tomorrow&message=Hi%20folks%2C%20kicking%20off%20a%20chat%20about%20our%20meeting%20tomorrow

However, I need to post a message to a specific channel and not to specific users

Comment: @Zen, The best way to send message to channel is to use the message api. Check the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#http-request). They are straight forward to use.
In case you want to continue with the same approach - you need to build ur url, check this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links#generating-a-deep-link-to-your-tab) for how you can build your url.

Comment: Thank you @Abhijit-MSFT, I am trying to avoid using graph API for now if there is a way to use deeplink URI for this. I have already read the link you have sent for creating deep links, but unfortunately i can only see how to create a deep link that will put a message to chat with specific users and not on the a Team Channel.

Comment: @ZenLang, In Channel you can not send message using deeplink. You need to use api's

Comment: thanks @Abhijit-MSFT, I guess we have no choice but to use Graph API

Comment: @Abhijit-MSFT ~ You should write an answer explaining this requirement, so future users can see the correct answer instead of having to dig through the comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use share-to-teams button for posting message to teams channel withtout using api.

Comment: But not to a specific team - user must enter the channel every time they publish. So it doesn't quite meet the requirement here

Answer (score 0):

It really looks like MS doesn't support doing this via a simple URL (as of October 2021). As noted, the graph API should provide a way to do it but is complex to setup and get started with.

The best option I've found is to use an HTML mailto: link (see https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/html/how-to-create-mailto-links.html) and set the mail's "To" to the address from the team's "..." > "Get email address" dialog.

This pops up a compose window in your mail client (e.g. Outlook) and all you have to do is click Send to post it to your team channel. It supports passing through formatted text, and the email's subject is displayed prominently as the title of a new MS Teams Conversation.